# How can I recover from UNMOUNTALBE_BOOT_VOLUME error on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, crash, reboot, ccleaner

My win XP machine was running really slow so i decided (not a great idea in hindsight) to download and run CCleaner.  I cleaned up files and registry settings (it makes you save a backup) and then i went to reboot the next day and now Windows wont start.

I basically get:

1. The "You machine didn't shutdown properly message" where you can choose "Safe mode", etc..
2. No matter what choice I make (safe mode, last good configuration, normal mode, etc), it tries to start up windows then shows up a blue screen with a bunch of stuff but the main error is:

   ```
    UNMOUNTALBE_BOOT_VOLUME
   ```
3. Then goes back to the Dell boot up screen and then back to step 1

Has anyone else experienced this?  Are there any other suggestions on how to have my machine start up again or do you think its hosed?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I back up most of my files but I still hope the machine isn't worthless now.  Any help would be appreciated to try to get back into Windows.

Answer (score 1):

judging from the cause of the issue, your best bet is to run a filesystem check from your Windows XP installation CD. here are some instructions to do that from Microsoft's website.

> 1.Insert the Windows XP CD-ROM into the CD-ROM drive, and then restart the computer.
>
> Click to select any options that are required to start the computer
>   from the CD-ROM drive if you are prompted.
>
> 2.When the "Welcome to Setup" screen appears, press R to start the Recovery Console.
>
> 3.If you have a dual-boot or multiple-boot computer, select the installation that you must access from the Recovery Console.
>
> 4.When you are prompted, type the Administrator password. If the administrator password is blank, just press ENTER.
>
> 5.At the command prompt, type chkdsk /r , and then press ENTER.
>
> 6.At the command prompt, type exit , and then press ENTER to restart your computer.

Comment: +1 for `chkdsk /r`. That has solved half a dozen similar boot problems at my last job.  @parasheps boot via CD method is probably the easiest solution for home usage. Putting the disk in another computer as second HDD also works.